# Flutter: Is nesting FutureBuilder results unusual behaviour?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-futurebuilder

While I was doing my project I encounter unforeseen condition where if I open a page where I have nested FutureBuilder widget then going back to another page and focusing on text field to type something resulted navigation to the same page where i have nested futurebuilder.

```
     _UserProfileState() {
    FromSharedPref().getString('userId').then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userId = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          AppUser user = AppUser.fromJason(snapshot.data.data());
          return ProfileForm(
            user: user,
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

When I tired to get the sharedPreference data using future builder then I encountered that error. But it was gone when I removed nested futureBuilder.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If your program needs nested FutureBuilders because it is structured that way, then you can do that.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I still don't see a nested FutureBuilder.